# jquery is not working with visual force pages

Tags: jquery, salesforce

i have written very simple javascript function

```
function menuClass(id) {
jQuery(".active").removeClass("active");
jQuery("#"+id).addClass("active");
```

}

but when i am using the function in visualforce pages

it is not working

this is visualforce page line where i am using it

```
<li id="ayurveda"><apex:outputLink value="panchkarmaayurveda" id="ayurvedaLink" onclick="menuClass('ayurveda');">Ayurveda</apex:outputLink>
```

also i have called this function onload event

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
```

what is the problem this function is working also not giving error 
tried with firebug

here is the link where i have actually used it 
[Panchkarma Ayurveda](http://www.panchakarmayurveda.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to assign jQuery.noConflict() to a unique variable and then use that variable inside of the menuClass method, i.e.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and

```
function menuClass(id) {
  $j(".active").removeClass("active");
  $j("#"+id).addClass("active");
}
```

For further information, you can take a look at http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page